# Foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I am learning about database, I need to know something about the foreign key in MySQL.

Consider the following two tables.

1. UserGroupType.
2. UserGroup.

**UserGroupType:**

[image]

**UserGroup:**

[image]

In this table the foreign key is defined as follows,

**foreign key   (GroupType_id) references UserGroupType(GroupType_id)**

I just want to know whether the name of the field in UserGroup can be changed? consider the following altered statement.

**GroupType:**
[image]

**foreign key (Type_id) references UserGroupType(GroupType_id)**

Is it necessary that both the field names must be same?

How to set the default value for datetime?

Thanks in advance, sorry if it is very basic things.

Comment: No, it's not necessary for the two column names to be identical. But it's good practice. When you'll have lot of tables and queries with more than 1-2 joins, it helps to have the same name to join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreign key would have a different name from the primary key it is referring to, but necessarily , their *data type* and other *attributes* should be the same.
for example , if one is `INT(10) unsigned` the other should be defined the same.

but sometimes it is a good practice to name them similarly in complex queries. for example when you want to JOIN the relating tables, you can use the syntax :

```
userGroupType INNER JOIN userGroup USING (GroupType_id)
```

instead of :

```
userGroupType INNER JOIN userGroup ON userGroupType.GroupType_id = userGroup.GroupType_id
```